# Body overflow-y hidden, onclick

Tags: javascript, css

I happily use this simple (on click) function to enable my 100%-100% sized iframe's visibility:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function newwindow() {
            var showme = document.getElementById("frame");
            showme.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
</script>
```

Now.. within the same function, **I'd like to disable the vertical scrolling** (on the parent page's body).

I googled for hours. Stuck! I tried stuff like this:

```
document.getElementById('myBodyID').style.overflowY='hidden'

(document.getElementById('myBodyID').style["overflow-y"]).
```

and more, but nothing good happens. It looks like the 'overflow'has problems, in fact I made a quick test with this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
```

and it worked correctly, page turned yellow. But the same logic is not working with body's 'overflow'.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `myBodyID` refers to a real element and that this is the element you want to change?

Comment: So why didnt you try to use `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` ?

Comment: I did try, it's just not working.

Comment: Post a JS Fiddle demo not working, because [**your code works fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6fy32bg/)... (Scroll down to see the blue button)

Answer (score 0):

For the code to work as written, your `<body>` needs to be `<body id="myBodyID">`

The syntax is just

`document.getElementById("myBodyID").style.overflowY = "scroll";`

You may have to wait until window load if that script is called in `<head>`; body doesn't exist yet. Document ready is technically sufficent but that's non-trivial without jQuery. Alternatively, move the script to  the bottom of your page, or just use CSS.

Comment: Hum indeed it makes sense (also KJ Prince is saying similarly).

I just made a try with <body id="myBodyID">, but still no results on my page...

Comment: Try moving your script to just before `</html>` and see what happens

Comment: Plz see above the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
</style>
<script>
            function newwindow() {
            var showme = document.getElementById("frame");
            showme.style.visibility = "visible";
            document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
            }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="newwindow()">
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://armblog.net">
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I love you all.

Listen, I did try all the mentioned options and all of them where correct (thanks).

**But** it was not working in my html, why?

I just found out the reason: In my css I had: body overflow-**x**: hidden; that was working ok for me and it was looking innocent.

*Actually it was preventing the mentioned script to work. I dunno why. I removed it just to make a stupid try, now it all works good.*

Cheers!